# Best Way for Developers to Upload Files to Production Server

Tags: untagged

Small team of developers doing their work here and there. We have a team leader, and is sole responsible for uploading updated source files from the development server to the production server. So let's say, so if an updated files needs to be uploaded to the prod server, that concerned developer shall notify the team lead about it, and then the team lead will update the files to the prod server. So no developer has an access to the prod server except for the team lead. That's our current setup.

Now, what we want to do is to give developers a way for uploading their updated files to the server without the team lead intervening in the process. What do you think is the best way to go about this?

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all RS (revision system) like Mercurial, git... can do push to different remote resository via SSH.

so your devs can work on their own repo, or locally based repo, and from time to time push to remote repo which would be this 'production' server.

Comment: do you think this is a good idea, giving devs facility to update production? thanks! j

Comment: Your question was too vague. So your problem is policy than technical aspect?

I'm not a project leader but what you name 'production' server should be called 'tested release'. Of course the one who marks a code as 'release' should have an authority, others should not do.

Very nice presentation about project leading and release/testing is from Theo http://www.openbsd.org/papers/asiabsdcon2009-release_engineering/index.html